# get float value from nsdata objective-c iOS

Tags: objective-c, nsdata

I am trying to get a float value from a `NSData` object which contains several hex values. e.g. EC 51 38 41
From this 4 Byte values i want to get the float value 11.52. How do i have to do this in xcode?

I have tried it with `NSScanner` (scanFloat, scanHexFloat), `NSNumberformatter` and `NSNumber`, i created an Byte Array and tried `float myFloat = *(float*)&myByteArray`. All these Options i found here at stackoverflow.

I tested it in Windows with C# and there it was no problem:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[4] { 0xEC, 0x51, 0x38, 0x41 };

float myFloat = System.BitConverter.ToSingle(bytes, 0);
```

Does anybody know how i have to do this in xcode???

Thanks, Benjamin

Answer (score 5):

When converting binary data from a foreign protocol always make sure to include proper swapping for endianness:

```
uint32_t hostData = CFSwapInt32BigToHost(*(const uint32_t *)[data bytes]);
float value = *(float *)(&hostData);
```

You have to know the endianness of the encoded data. You might need to use `CFSwapInt32LittleToHost` instead.

Answer (score 3):

```
NSData * data = ...; // loaded from bluetooth
float z;
[data getBytes:&z length:sizeof(float)];
```

Try this.

Answer (score 0):

> I have tries it with NSScanner (scanFloat, scanHexFloat), NSNumberformatter and NSNumber

You're barking up the wrong tree here. `NSScanner` is for scanning strings. `NSNumber` is not the same as `NSData`, and `NSNumberFormatter` won't work with `NSData` either.

`NSData` is a container for plain old binary data. You've apparently got a `float` stored in an `NSData` instance; if you want to access it, you'll need to get the data's `bytes` and then interpret those bytes however you like, e.g. by casting to `float`:

```
float *p = (float*)[myData bytes];   // -bytes returns a void* that points to the data
float f = *p;
```