# Convert NSData bytes

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, nsdata

By reverse engineering a Bluetooth transmission from my body scale, I got a NSData object that contains 3 float values, 1 or 2 int and a string. Unfortunately, I have no idea how to extract those from the NSData.

`<9f781e00 fea27b4b 09000000 ff000000 ff000900>` (First float should be 78.0)

`<9f821e00 fe387c4b 09000000 ff000000 ff000900>` (First float should be 78.1)

I assume, they are in the order: float string float float int (int).
How do I get the values from NSData? :)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18437535/get-float-value-from-nsdata-objective-c-ios

Comment: Thanks, but I've tried that and its not working.

Comment: Are you sure about this record format? The string is fixed at four bytes and in the middle of the record?

Comment: Actually, no. That was a guess. I just saw that the first part was the same, depending on the weight (which was 78.1 a few times and the first byte stayed the same). I am not sure about that though.

Comment: I don't think you have the right piece of data. Reading out 78.0 in hex should look like 00009c42 (little-endian).